# Flume - What happens if client batch-size is larger than Channel Transaction Capacity?

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I was reading [Batch Size, Channel Capacity Channel Transaction Capacity.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/BatchSize,+ChannelCapacity+and+ChannelTransactionCapacity+Properties)  I'm a bit confused, let's say a client's Batch Size is 200 but the Channel's Transaction Capacity is 100.  What happens:

- Does the client downgrade its batch-size to match the channel's capacity?
- Does the client put the events into the channel in 2 transactions?
- Would the client attempt to put 200 events in one transaction and receive an exception?

I thought someone may already know this, if I don't hear back I'll do an experiment ;-)

Does this mean one has to update these settings when a new client is added?

Answer (score 0):

At least in regards to `FileChannel` and `HDFSEventSink` the `FileChannel.ChannelCapacity` has to be bigger than the `HDFSEventSink.batchSize`  Otherwise you'd get an [exception](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flume-user/201303.mbox/%3CCFA73F1CD063634CB7C435EBBC36BA4B0D467DE6EA@cnvr-exch01%3E).